# Will product model numbers change based on product variants/attributes like size,color

Tags: configurable-product, sku

Will product model numbers change based on product variants/attributes like size,color.

As in an early discussion , I understand every product will have a unique SKU to identify the product 
So how is product model number( as in different product types), SKU , product names related . 
Will product model number remain same across multiple variants of a product

Comment: If my answer is answering your question completely, please set it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you create a product with variants/attributes as you say, it is called a "**configurable product**". In Magento, a configurable product is associated to **simple products**.

**Each simple product** can have its own colour, size (the variants or attributes you are talking about), and also **have its own SKU**. The configurable product will then take all those simple products and "merge" them into a single product, where you will be able to select the attributes.

When you will order your configurable product, its SKU will be associated to the order, but also the SKU of the simple product.

Don't worry about having to set many and many SKUs, you can create simple products directly from configurable products, and it will create a unique SKU at this time, from the attributes selected.